# MySql Module shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

i try to use MySql in XAMPP but the error below appears each time. i don't know if the problem is caused by the used port or there is another problem.

This is the message that appears:

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:44:59  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
20:44:59  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

Answer (score 0):

click config and choose my.ini

and change the port to 8111

[image]